# yum install R dependency issue (RHEL 5.5)

Tags: rhel, yum, dependencies, r

I'm trying to remotely install R on a RHEL 5.5 system but keep getting a dependency issue

```
yum -y install R
```

results in the following

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R.x86_64 0:3.3.0-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: R-devel = 3.3.0-3.el5 for package: R
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:3.3.0-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: R-core-devel = 3.3.0-3.el5 for package: R-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.3.0-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: R-core = 3.3.0-3.el5 for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: xz-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: texinfo-tex for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.3.0-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: xdg-utils for package: R-core
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.0()(64bit) for package: R-core
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.3.0-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: xz-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: texinfo-tex for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.3.0-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.0()(64bit) for package: R-core
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.3.0-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: xz-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: texinfo-tex for package: R-core-devel
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel
---> Package xdg-utils.noarch 0:1.0.2-4.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
R-core-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: liblzma.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package R-core-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: xz-devel is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: tk-devel is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: tcl-devel is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: texinfo-tex is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: xz-devel is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: liblzma.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package R-core-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: tcl-devel is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: tk-devel is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: texinfo-tex is needed by package R-core-devel-3.3.0-3.el5.x86_64 (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I've tried `yum clean all` as possible solution but it results in the same issue. I've also tried to install the dependencies separately but they don't seem to exist.

How can I resolve this, and why might the package manager think a dependency is missing when it doesn't actually exist?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS 5.5 is pretty old. It came out back in 2010. EPEL targets the latest release in a major, meaning it targets 5.11. You're pretty far behind and expecting EPEL to support you.

My guess is that you need to update. There may be some packages you depend on that ship only with newer versions of 5.x.

A reminder that 5.x stopped getting fixes in 2014 and will be completely EOL in less than a year. You should have some kind of update plan.